# PHP/MYSQL Most popular query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a function that returns an array of idnumbers (for pages) based on the number of views of the page ranked by number of views.  Every time someone views table, there is a new row.  So I basically need to count the rows but do so by pageid.  I'm thinking it uses count but  SQL is not my strong suit.  Can anyone suggest the proper way to do this?

```
table 'views':

id | pageid | 

SELECT COUNT(id) from views WHERE pageid== '22' ORDER BY COUNT(id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT pageid, COUNT(id) FROM views 
WHERE pageid== '22' 
GROUP BY pageid 
ORDER BY COUNT(id)
```

Comment: I forgot I need to join it with two other tables, users and topages.  The query without most popular is SELECT t.short,t.whenadded,t.id,t.userid,u.ID,u.uid
FROM `topages` t
LEFT JOIN `users` u
ON t.userid = u.ID
WHERE (short LIKE '%$str%' OR long LIKE '%$str%')";

Comment: It worked...How would I echo Count(id)?  I tried setting $row equal to the query results and calling echo $row['count(id)']; but that did not work.  Also tried $row['count(v.id)'] as it is part of a join and setting those to variables but no go.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Add an alias to `COUNT(id)`, something like `COUNT(id) AS countid`

Answer (score 1):

I would post this as a comment, but I apparently don't have access to comment yet...

> How would I echo Count(id)?

Assign an alias like so:

```
SELECT pageid, COUNT(id) as viewcount FROM views 
WHERE pageid== '22' 
GROUP BY pageid 
ORDER BY COUNT(id)
```

Then you can access the row with:

```
echo $row['viewcount'];
```

Sorry I can't help with the joins part - I've never had much luck joining tables while using functions like count or group by.